# Remove a Hidden Form Element from a Specific/Selected Form

Tags: jquery, forms

I am adding form elements within a modal to a form in the parent page.  That form's ID is file_form.

However, when the person UN checks the checkbox, I also need to remove any current hidden inputs tied to the file_form form.  I have seen how to generally remove hidden form elements using .remove, but not how to specifically remove them from a specific form?  Here is what I tried:

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     var thecat = $(this).val();

$('#file_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="caty[]" value='+ thecat + ' />');
} else {

 $('#file_form').append($('input[type="hidden"][value="'+thecat+'"]').remove());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('#file_form input[type="hidden"]').remove();
```

`$('#file_form input[type="hidden"]')` find all the `type="hidden input` elements in the element with id `file_form`

Comment: I am not wanting to remove all inputs. Just the specific one with that "thecat" value.  Is this what I would use then?

`code`$('#file_form input[type="hidden"][value="'+thecat+'"]').remove();

(Note, I tried that and it actually is not working.)

Comment: @CRAIG can make http://jsfiddle.net/ or you have live link or you can reproduce the scenario .